# Passing String [] args values to another class

Tags: java, string, variables, queue, args

I have a command line input as 0 1 2 and the main code can be seen below.

```
public class AppleStoreRunner {
   public static void main(String [] args) {

        //maximum size of queue
        int qCapacity = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        //number of simulation hours
        int simHours = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        //average number of customers per hour
        int custPerHour = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        AppleStore myStore = new AppleStore(qCapacity, simHours, custPerHour);

        //Run simulation
        myStore.simulation();
        myStore.displayAcceptedCustomers();
        myStore.displayServedCustomers();
        myStore.displayWaitingCustomers();
        myStore.displayTurnAwayCustomers();

    }
}
```

How can I call the inputed command line arguments in the following class so that I may use the inputs in a seperate extended class? The code below is the class I am trying to create variables for the 3 inputed numbers.

```
public class AppleStore {

 int qCapacity;
 int simHours;
 int custPerHour;

/** Constructor 
* @param qCapacity The initial capacity of the queue to be used. 
* @param simHours The number of hours that the simulation should run. 
* @param custPerHour expected number of customers to arrive per hour. 
 */ 
     public AppleStore(int qCapacity, int simHours, int custPerHour) 

     {
         qCapacity = AppleStoreRunner.main(args);
     }
 /** 
     * This methods performs a simulation of a store operation using a queue and prints the statistics. 
     * For every minute, the simulator 1) checks if there are new customers arriving; 2) adds the new customer into the waiting line or else records the customer who chooses to leave; 3) continues to help the current customer if the current customer is not finished yet, or else get the next person in the waiting line. The simulator starts at minute 0, and repeats every minute until it finishes the requested simulation time.  
     */ 
     public void simulation( ) 
     {
     System.out.println( "Average Waiting Time" + );
     System.out.println( "Average Line Length" + );

     /** 
     *  print the info of all accepted customers 
     */ 
     }
      public void displayAcceptedCustomers() 
      {
          System.out.println("Customers accepted" + );

     /** 
     * print the info of all served customers 
     */ 
      }
      public void displayServedCustomers() 

      /** 
      * print the info of all waiting customers 
      */ 
      public void displayWaitingCustomers() 

     /** 
     * print the info of all turned away customers 
     */ 
     public void displayTurnAwayCustomers() 

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an infinitely recursive program?  I don't get this.  Your `main` method creates a new `AppleStore`, which calls the constructor, which calls `main`, which creates a new `AppleStore`, which ... If your goal is to try to blow up the Apple Store by making it stack-overflow, I doubt that will work.  :) :)

Answer (score 5):

Because you did `AppleStore myStore = new AppleStore(qCapacity, simHours, custPerHour);` in your main method, all you need to do is to define a proper constructor.

```
public AppleStore(int qCapacity, int simHours, int custPerHour) 

{
    this.qCapacity = qCapacity;
    this.simHours = simHours;
    this.custPerHour = custPerHour;
}
```

As you declared the three instance variables as package-private, the subclasses will automatically see the existence of the three variables.

However, if you make the subclasses somehow immune to the changes to the superclass (I mean, the `AppleStore`), I recommend to add some getters for the three variables than can be called from the subclasses such as:

```
int getQueueCapacity() {
    return this.qCapacity;
}
```

and to change the access levels of the three variables into private.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought my constuctor in main was private thus assuming a new constructor was needed.